# jquery mobile popup / dialog and paged MVC Page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

i'm having a problem with jqueryMobile popup widget.
HTML (via jquery mobile Site):

```
 <a id="testId" href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
            <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
        </div>
```

besides that on the page is  an MVC3 Pager:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Items, page => Url.Action("ListA", "List", new { page }))
```

all the scripts are loaded, jqyerymobile is loaded (checked using $.mobile)

the test scenario:

1. i open a page:

   > List/ListA

   and click on a link to show the dialog.  - Works
2. i change the page of the paged List, so my URL changes to

   > List/ListA?page=2

   i click on the show dialog link - nothing.
3. i go back to page 1 of the paged list, click show popup, Nothing.

   But:
4. when i enter a page URL like  List/ListA?page=2 and load the page from scratch ( like a new tab, or window) , the popup works on this page, until pagesList page change.
5. when on step 2 i force the reload of the page by using Ctrl+R / Crtl+F5 (depending on the browser) it starts to work on this page.

tried also all combinations of

```
$('#..').popup('open')
.popup('close'), etc,
```

It all points me to thinking, that some part of initiation like creating jquerymobile widgets fails on pages with &page=something.
the markup is all there, selectors correctly select the popup element, but open simply doesn't work.

Or maybe when the page is reloaded on a different paged List position, some objects remain in the browsers context what prevents them from being re-created on new page, hence some valid, but not working references.. i don't  know.

Can anybody provide me with come clue, to why this is happening?

jquery mobile version: 1.3.1

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: mobile: 1.3.1
jquery (base) 1.9.1